Angular variable value change not reflecting in @if condition
I am changing the value of my isEditing variable to show that the edit button has been clicked. This should show input field in a table row. I am using angular material table but I don't think this matters.
Changing the value of the variable during start in the .ts shows the required change but again clicking the button the input doesn't toggle (Edit/Cancel functionality)
@if (innerColumn == "Amount" && isEditing) {
  //some code here
} @else {
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let innerElement">
    {{ innerColumn + "-" + isEditing }}
  </td>
}

The else condition is always triggered and it shows the isEditing variable takes values both true and false but this doesn't show up in @if.
I tried using debugger and displaying in the screen. The value is shown in the screen but the if condition is not triggered.

This code is a syntax error for me. What is the =&& operator supposed to do? Did you intent to write @if (innerColumn === " Amount" && isEditing) ?

Also you have a leading space here " Amount". Is this intended?

yeah remove the = from =&&

@JSONDerulo Yes it got added while writing the question. I have edited it. There is no console error. Also the check condition innerColumn=="Amount" is working fine. It is the isEditing variable which does not respond to change

@PrateekTewary Try importing private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef and then call this.cdr.detectChanges() on the place where you update the variable isEditing

@NarenMurali Did that but nothing changed. Even console logging the value shows that it is changing from true to false and vice versa but the if condition does not run. If I change the value of the variable isEditing in the .ts file then the if condition evaluates to that value.

@PrateekTewary above the HTML log the {{isEditing}} | {{innerColumn == "Amount" && isEditing}}<br/> @if (innerColumn == "Amount" && isEditing) { check if its updating in this spot, also check if the total condition is correct

@NarenMurali, Yah I did that. In the @else it shows the value of isEditing changes from true to false. would checking it above make any difference?

@PrateekTewary If {{innerColumn == "Amount" && isEditing}} does not toggle, then its a problem with the condition inside the if condition, if it does toggle, then there is a bug in angular, let me know which it is. I want to know if the condition above toggles properly in HTML

Probably mat-table is reading the matCellDef element as the cell template and after that I doesn't care if the condition changes.
Try moving the condition inside the matCellDef element.

Did you debug the DOM to see if the element is present?  It may be styling.
